# Getting “Platform application is disabled” from Amazon SNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, amazon-sns

I want to send notifications to ios  device using amazon sns service

but the code return  Platform application is disabled
how can I fix it

Answer (score 14):

I check the expired date of p12 files using getPlatformApplicationAttributes method in the SnsClient

then I update the file of p12 now it work fine .

Comment: +1 Same problem/solution for me. That error message was not clear (currently undocumented) and had me running in circles trying to figure it out. Thanks for following up on your question!!

Answer (score 5):

This error is caused when the `p12` file you have uploaded to AWS is expired.

So go to AWS, create new one and follow the instuctions from the url below.

https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/create-push-notification-platform-for-aws-sns-ae6c845735b4

Comment: Consider adding the steps from the provided link to your answer. Adding links as an answer is not acceptable in SO.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this happen when I tried to send a notification to a device I did not have access to send to just FYI so it doesn't have to be just the cert that is wrong